# Docker working on localhost but have an empty containers running list

Tags: docker

Yesterday I decided to learn docker and use it for a prestashop project so I created a `docker-compose.yml` my goal was to run a prestashop with a phpmyadmin and mysql all linked together.

Before leaving yesterday I didn't want to lose everything I had done so I ran a `docker save` and a `docker commit`, so I thought whenever I come back I can just run the save I made and run it without losing anything (like a snapshot).

Everything was working, containers were running and today when I try to run a `docker ps -a` **I have an empty output**. However my project is still working on `localhost:8080` for **prestashop** and `localhost:8081` for my phpmyadmin.

**How could I find back the containers and also save them so I can use them on another computer?**

`docker-compose.yml` :

```
version: "3.8"
 services:
  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    container_name: db
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
    networks:
      - dev

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin:latest
    container_name: phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - 8081:80
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
    networks:
      - dev

  apache:
    build: php
    container_name: prestashop
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - ./php/vhosts:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled
      - ./:/var/www/html
    restart: always
    networks:
      - dev

networks:
  dev:

volumes:
  db-data:
```

`Dockerfile` :

```
FROM php:7.4-apache

RUN echo "ServerName localhost" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends locales apt-utils git libicu-dev g++ libpng-dev libxml2-dev libzip-dev libonig-dev libxslt-dev;

RUN echo "en_US.UTF8 UTF8" > /etc/locale.gen && \
    echo "fr_FR.UTF-8 UTF-8" >> /etc/locale.gen && \
    locale-gen

RUN curl -sSk https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --disable-tls && \
    mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

RUN docker-php-ext-configure intl
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql gd opcache intl zip calendar dom mbstring zip gd xsl
RUN pecl install apcu && docker-php-ext-enable apcu
RUN a2enmod rewrite && service apache2 restart
RUN chown -R www-data:w
```

**Output for** `docker images` :

```
REPOSITORY          TAG          IMAGE ID       CREATED       SIZE
prestadock_apache   latest       740c640530f3   2 days ago    657MB
phpmyadmin          latest       f7fd780fedba   7 days ago    469MB
php                 7.4-apache   899ab23566b7   7 days ago    414MB
mysql               latest       c8562eaf9d81   10 days ago   546MB
```

**Output for** `docker network ls`

```
NETWORK ID     NAME             DRIVER    SCOPE
e03870bf5fec   bridge           bridge    local
63cfaacfbb2e   chronopiles      bridge    local
c23a0b85edb9   host             host      local
1ae1b68b12c0   none             null      local
1e8010db79e3   prestadock_dev   bridge    local
590b5e949037   prestashop       bridge    local
```

Comment: The easier approach is pushing all images to the docker hub and copy just the docker-compose.yml file in another pc and run docker-compose up command. Do want this?

Comment: I'll check for the docker hub, but I can't find my containers

Comment: do you have dockerhub account?

Comment: yes, I do have one. But the current problem is that I can't figure out where are my containers and why I can't write in my project

Comment: follow the anwser below

Comment: you have removed the line about running the project universally or in other computers. Which may lead my answer to another meaning and I can get penalty from other users. could you please edit your question? And accept my answer if it works.

Comment: Sorry I had a warning about asking 2 questions in 1 post

Comment: because your title is somehow a little confusing with actual body. Your question should be "Docker working in local machine but how can I save it for global use" or something like that.

Comment: Yes but the question was not about that, I would like to know why my project is still working even if I can't see the container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easier approach is pushing your images to the docker hub and just copying yml file to another pc and run `docker-compose up` command. To achieve this you have to add imagename with your docker hub user name like this:

```
version: "3.8"
 services:
  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    container_name: db
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
    networks:
      - dev

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin:latest
    container_name: phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - 8081:80
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
    networks:
      - dev

  apache:
    build: php
    image: benju1/prestashop
    container_name: prestashop
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - ./php/vhosts:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled
      - ./:/var/www/html
    restart: always
    networks:
      - dev

networks:
  dev:

volumes:
  db-data:
```

To push the docker images to docker hub follow this command instruction by opening shell or commandline in the folder of docker-compose.yml file

- Type `docker login` and enter
- Enter your docker hub credentials to login
- type `docker-compose build .` and enter to build your images
- type `docker-compose push` and enter to push the images in your dockerhub

then copy your docker-compose.yml file in your other computer and just type
`docker-compose up -d`  to run your project.

Comment: Ok so whenever I create a container and I want to share it I must save him as an image, push it to my docker-hub and write in the docker-compose.yml file the image name. Thanks for your quick response.

Comment: In this case, only one image will be pushed because the other two images are not owned by you. You can own them too by tagging and creating a new image. But that is not necessary. that's why you see that for only one image we put your repository name.

Comment: and you can push to your custom private container registry instead of putting in public registry in docker hub. The other container registries are like "Azure container registry", "Amazon Elastic Container Registry" etc.